# Control width of knitr output for columns in sweave documents

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

According to [FAQ.7](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md) and [Example.038](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/038-output-width.Rnw), I should be able to control my width through global options `options(width=40)` or chunk options `tidy.opts(width.cutoff=40)`. However, the text still runs off the gray box, and in my current case where I have two-column beamer slides. the source code runs into the next column. Is there anything else I can do besides turning off tidy `tidy=FALSE` and manually setting the breaks in my code?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<>>=
library(reshape2)
options(width=38)
@ 
\begin{columns}[t]
  \column{.5\textwidth}
  <<>>=
  dataframe <- data.frame(Column1=1:10,Column2=1:10,Variable=1:10,Value=1:10)
  @ 
  \column{.5\textwidth}
  <<>>=
  dataframe <- melt(dataframe,
  id.vars=c("Column1","Column2"),
  variable.name="Variable",
  value.name="Value")
  @ 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output (problem is that columns run together):

[image]

Comment: Please supply a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: have you tried the basic chunk options? Particularly `out.width`?

Comment: `out.width` is for figures. Anything for text output besides `width.cutoff`?

Comment: you could set `tidy = FALSE` to clean up the formatting. But as it says in the example, your output is too wide--you are taking the total line width and splitting it into two columns of equal width but you also have to account for the wasted white space between the columns.

Comment: ...I already suggest the `tidy=FALSE` in my original question. But seriously though the text overflow in the image above seems to be significantly more than what is due to the wasted space between columns or along the margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options should be passed like this:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(comment="", message=FALSE,tidy.opts=list(keep.blank.line=TRUE, width.cutoff=120),options(width=100), cache=TRUE,fig.align='center',fig.height=6, fig.width=10,fig.path='figure/beamer-',fig.show='hold',size='footnotesize', cache=TRUE)
@
```

And here you specify `width.cutoff` for code and `width` for r results.

Comment: You can also check possible chunk options at [author's page](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) but it took me a while to collect all options I always desired :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work currently